# Image quality for multi page Tiff

Tags: image, image-processing

Folks - I am new to Image Processing and looking for guidance if I am using the right approach. We have ton of multi page Tiff Images that span atleast 15-20 pages long. The quality of image is sometimes good and sometimes not good. Here is my thought process to improve the quality of the image and please feel free to correct.

a) I would like to first estimate the image quality score. Is that possible for black/white, complete text image.

b) If I determine the score is low then i would like to use methods to enhance the quality of the image.

I have attached a sampleC:\fakepath\2019-09-09_8-58-11.png(/upfiles/1568044740803077.png)(/upfiles/15680447268662473.png)

(Note : The images are from the same TIFF document on multiple pages , I saved them as .png for screenshots to this post)

Tried to use OpenCV and also PyTesseract but OCR did not work on low quality images.

Get image quality of score and if score is low do some image processing using OpenCV or deep learning to improve the overall quality.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To improve image quality, re-scan the documents correctly. If you can't read it, there's no way you're going to get a computer to read it.

Comment: Thanks Cris , that would be ideal but image re-acquisition time is expensive. These are documents scanned a while back. Appreciate your feedback.